# MacBook Pro 15" 2018 Touch Bar right side buttons / icons not lit (they stay dark, for example Siri and mute volume icons)

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I have a rather strange problem with the Touch Bar of my MacBook Pro 2018. I noticed a while ago that suddenly the rightmost side of the Touch Bar is dark, I can't see the Siri icon for example anymore. The button itself works, so Siri comes on.

Here is a photo of the situation:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pezj3b0yx3tmvv/touchbar.jpg?dl=0

As you can see even the 'mute volume' icon is kind of half showing up, it seems like the 'lights' (for the lack of a better term) don't come up on the rightmost side of the Touch Bar. Does anybody have any idea what might cause this issue? I have come across some posts where people describe that the Touch Bar doesn't lit up at all but never something like this (where it is only partially lit). Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you try rebooting your MBP or resetting PRAM/NVRAM (turn on your MBP while pressing the Command+Option+P+R keys) ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and sorry for my late reply! Rebooting didn't help but I will try reseting PRAM/NVRAM and see if that helps. Thanks for your help!